# I4GL to .NET — trying to understand decimal and int

Tags: c#, informix, 4gl

Coming from .NET, I'm trying to understand the following.

```
DEFINE total_real DECIMAL(12,5)
DEFINE total_dec  DECIMAL(6,5)
DEFINE total_int  SMALLINT

LET total_real = (total_real / 50)      
LET total_int = total_real
LET total_dec = total_real - total_int
```

What is the purpose of `total_real - total_int`?

I tried to do some similar with C# but can't do it without first converting `total_int` to `double`/`decimal`. Is this just converting a `decimal` to `int`?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the manual on the 4GL!

It appears that the code is taking a "real number", dividing it by 50, and then getting the 'whole number' and 'decimal fraction' parts.

Answer (score 1):

The code is written dangerously, but as [Richard Scheider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431359/richard-schneider) surmised in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058569/15168), the intent is to get the integer and fractional parts of the number.

The problem is that `SMALLINT` is a 16-bit quantity with a range of ±32,767 (-32,768 is reserved to represent NULL).  And a `DECIMAL(12,5)` can accept values up to 9,999,999.99999 in magnitude.  And that number divided by 50 is a lot bigger than the range of values that fits in a `SMALLINT`.

Doing the job in 'all decimal', you might use:

```
DEFINE total_real DECIMAL(12,5)
DEFINE total_dec  DECIMAL(6,5)
DEFINE total_frac DECIMAL(6,0)

LET total_real = (total_real / 50)      
LET total_int  = TRUNC(total_real)
LET total_frac = total_real - total_int
```

Alternatively, simply change `SMALLINT` to `INTEGER`.  `INTEGER` is a 32-bit signed quantity.